# new Date() turning date into US format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, urlsearchparams

I'm  trying to compare a date from a URL, with today's date.  (I want to check, if the date from the URL, is within 28 days, from today's date).

**Here's my code, which kinda works:**

```
let params              = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
let from                = params.get('from');
let searchDate          = new Date(from);
let currentDate         = new Date();
let timeDiff            = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - searchDate.getTime());
let diffDays            = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
console.log("from", from);
console.log("searchDate", searchDate);
console.log("currentDate", currentDate);
console.log("timeDiff", timeDiff);
console.log("timeDiff", timeDiff);
```

The problem I have, is that sometimes `searchDate` is being returned in US date format.  And therefore, my `diffDays` is wrong.

**Here's an example of the output/console.logs.**
In this example, the `from` variable, (a string), is UK date format, which is what I want.  (7th March 2021).

However, `searchDate` variable seems to read this, in US format, (3rd July 2021), which is not what I want.  In this example, it should read as Sat 7th March 2021).

```
from 07-03-2021
searchDate Sat Jul 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
currentDate Tue Jan 12 2021 09:55:48 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)
timeDiff 14821451980
diffDays 172
```

In this example, the `diffDays`, should be 54 days.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Reena

Comment: You must either put string in proper format for `Date` or use momentJs to tell from what format you want to parse string.

Comment: @Justinas - I can't use a framework for this. So is the problem `from` variable, is not in the correct date format?

Comment: MomentJS is library, not framework. And yes, if your date is `07-03-2021` even you can't tell if it's `m-d-Y` or `d-m-Y` format deciding only from date string